# Data Layer Variable return Type & Value showing Undefined in Google tag manager?

Tags: schema.org, google-tag-manager, json-ld

[image]

I applied product schema using JSON-LD script in google tag manager. For this i create:

- Custom-HTML tag in JSON-LD Script for product schema
- Trigger the tag(filter type: page URL, Contains, productcategory url
  as /product/)
- Three Data Layer Variable. **Not use any DOM Element that actully i am
  confused about how to set the type in DOM Element for individual datalayer variable(product).**

Then while previewing the product category page that for check is it actually work dynamically for every product page and also the three variable change page by page or not. but it's showing something like that. Custom HTML tag not fired and also Variable Undefined. What is the mistkae that i am doing. How can i solve the error and dynamically implement the change for every product page. Give a solution..